# Ruby Regex: Math on Backreferences

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to replace all minutes with hours in a file.

Assume a raw file like this:
120m
90m

Should change to:
2h
1.5h

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can live with it printing "2.0" instead of "2", you can just do:

```
"120m 90m".gsub(/(\d+)m/) { "#{$1.to_f / 60.0}h"}
#=> "2.0h 1.5h"
```

If you need it to print it without ".0", you need to check whether the number is evenly divisible by 60 and if so return `$1.to_i / 60` instead of `$1.to_f / 60.0`.

Alternatively you could call `to_s` on the float and remove `.0` if the string ends with ".0"

Answer (score 1):

addition to sepp2k's answer.

```
"120m 90m".gsub(/(\d+)m/) { "#{($1.to_f / 60.0).to_s.gsub(/\.0$/, '')}h"}
#=> "2h 1.5h"
```