# How to Perform Operations on Regex Backreference Matches in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

In javascript, I have a string which contains numbers, and I want to increment the values by one.

Example:

```
var string = "This is a string with numbers 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10";

var desiredResult = "This is a string with numbers 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11";
```

Using a regex, is it possible to perform operations (addition in this case) on the matched backreference?

A found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697225/ruby-regex-math-on-backreferences) using Ruby:

```
string.gsub(/(\d+)/) { "#{$1.to_i + 1}"}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`string.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a function as the second argument:

```javascript
var s1 = "This is a string with numbers 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10";
var s2 = s1.replace(/\d+/g, function(x) { return Number(x)+1; });
s2; // => "This is a string with numbers 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11"
```

Note that if you use matching groups then the first argument to the function will be the entire match and each following argument will be the numbered matching group.

```
var x = "This is x1, x2, x3.";
var y = x.replace(/x(\d+)/g, function(m, g1) {
  return "y" + (Number(g1)+1);
});
y; // => "This is y2, y3, y4."
```

Comment: fast. I ended up using arguments[n] (versus x) in my actual code (because I had multiple backreferences)

Answer (score 1):

Found it.

```
var string = "This is a string with Numbers 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10";
var desiredResult = "This is a string with Numbers 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11";
var actualResult = string.replace(/([0-9]+)/g, function() {
    return parseInt(arguments[1])+1 
});
console.log(actualResult)
```

Should have guessed an anonymous function would work.